# How do I fit a vertical navigation bar within a div?

Tags: html, css

I have a div which is 300px height. I am trying to build a vertical navigation bar inside the div. I would like to evenly divide every li  to fit within the div. I used height= auto, but it doesn't work. I read some articles and they recommend to divide the height by the amount of links I have. I don't know if that is the right solution. Can anyone help please???

```
<div id="menu"> <!--Menus starts here-->
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Stuff1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Stuff2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Stuff3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Stuff4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div> <!--End of verrical menu here-->


/*the menu starts here*/
#menu{
    background-color: yellow;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;


}
#menu ul{
    width: 95%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: purple;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

#menu li{
list-style: none;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: auto;

color:#fffafa;
font-family: helvetica;
font-size: 20px;
padding: 20px;
text-align: center;
border:2px solid black;
}

#menu li:hover{
    background-color: #ff4500;
    width: 90%;
}

#menu li{
    -webkit-transition:all .9s ease;
    -moz-transition:all .9s ease;
    -ms-transition:all .9s ease;
    transition:all .9s ease;
} /*end of the menu goes here*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using 5 items you should manually set the height of the li, example;

```
li {
height: 20%;
}
```

Comment: @Alexander , and you have to remove element's padding and border to fit properly.

Comment: @Taxellool you are right, I just removed them and it fits properly now. Thank you

Comment: Jay I also followed your advice

Comment: Of course yes sorry, If you do require padding on the li for whatever reason please ensure you set the padding using %, for example if you have a padding-top: 2%; padding-bottom: 2%; then set the height to the li to 16% (if you have 5 items)

Comment: Okay, thank you I see it now. Basically, If i choose to work with % I should pay attention with borders, and padding because they also required space

Answer (score 0):

Here is jquery if u want to have more li tags in ul, menu will  stay 300px or u can change and menu height. here u can see: http://jsfiddle.net/j3TU3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a=+$("#menu").height();
    var c=$("li").length;
    var aa=(a/c)-4;
    $("li").css({"height":aa});
});
```